# select data more than 365 days old in linq

Tags: c#, linq

This is my Table structure **t_physical_inventory**

```
dte_cycle_count | qty | location
```

i am using the following Linq query to get result

```
int number = 3;
List<t_physical_inventory> Location = (from c in dc.t_physical_inventories
                where (c.dte_cycle_count == null ||
                ((TimeSpan)(Convert.ToDateTime(c.dte_cycle_count) -
                        (DateTime.Now.Date))).Days > 365) 
                && (c.qty > 0)
                orderby (c.location)
                select c).Take(number).ToList();
```

**Problem :**
I am not able to get those records whose dte_cycle_count is greater than 365.

Comment: Should it not be the other way round. Can't remember top of my head, but I think you should be subtracting `dte_cycle_count` from `Today`

Comment: Why do you cast a `TimeSpan` to `TimeSpan`? Is the timespan positive at all? You can use the `Duration`-method to get the absolute value.

Comment: Do you mean 365 days or one year?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar 365 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
int number = 3;
List<t_physical_inventory> Location = null;
        Location = (from c in dc.t_physical_inventories
                    where (c.dte_cycle_count == null 
                       || (DateTime.Now.Date - Convert.ToDateTime(c.dte_cycle_count))
                               ).Days > 365) 
                       && (c.qty > 0)
                    orderby (c.location)
                    select c).Take(number).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TotalDays` as Timespan with 1 Year 12 Days returns 12 from `Days` but `TotalDays` return `Years * 365 + 12`

Furtermore you should substract the earlier date from the later date as Yahya suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is the timespan positive at all? You can use the [`Duration`-method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the absolute value:

```
List<t_physical_inventory> Location = null;
Location = (from c in dc.t_physical_inventories
            where (c.dte_cycle_count == null 
            || (c.dte_cycle_count.Value - DateTime.Now.Date).Duration.Days > 365)                  
               && (c.qty > 0)
            orderby (c.location)
            select c).Take(number).ToList();
```

However, this treats positive timespans the same way as negative. It's probably better to subtract the earlier `DateTime` from the later `DateTime` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that if you want data older than *one year*, you need to do it differently:

```
List<t_physical_inventory> Location = null;
Location = (from c in dc.t_physical_inventories
            where (c.dte_cycle_count == null || c.dte_cycle_count.Value < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)) && (c.qty > 0)
            orderby (c.location)
            select c).Take(number).ToList();
```